# Understanding ng-model for Select options

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

My controller:

```
$scope.taglist = [{"name":"Fruit_Type","value":"0"},
                  {"name":"Leaves_Arrangment","value":"?"},
                  {"na‌​me":"Leaves_Margin","value":"?"},
                  {"name":"Leaves_Type","value":"?"}];
```

Here is my form

```
<form id="filter_form" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" novalidate class="simple-form">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in tags.tags.objects | groupBy:'category.name'">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{ key }}
    </div>
    <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-repeat="(item_key, item) in value | groupBy:'subcategory.name'">
      <div class="input-label">
        {{ item_key }}
      </div>
      <select name="{{ key }}_{{ item_key }}" ng-model="taglist" ng-options="option.description for option in item">
        <option ng-value="">------</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
Currently selected: {{ taglist }}
```

Currently selected shows:

```
Currently selected: [{"name":"Fruit_Type","value":"0"},
                     {"name":"Leaves_Arrangment","value":"?"},
                     {"na‌​me":"Leaves_Margin","value":"?"},
                     {"name":"Leaves_Type","value":"?"}]
```

Why is the select options not set according to the $scope.taglist? Im under the impression that this is what is supposed to happen.
So Fruit Type should have options 0 selected, the rest none.

*Im just trying to get the form in the state as the taglist is in*

Comment: for select options to be set according to taglist then you should use
ng-options="value for description in taglist"

Comment: You say `ng-model="taglist"`, so currently selected is `$scope.taglist` - an array of objects. Seems right, but that's not what you want... See @CodingNinja 's comment for the content of `ngOptions` and use a different variable for `ngModel` (acutally the variable, that should just contain the select object, not the whole array).